# Bootstrap 3 : When I include bootstrap.js in my page all the links don't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website created using bootstrap 3. The structure of my site is like this

```
….
<body>
//bootsrap banner here..
.
.
//some links here ex. <a href=""..
.
.
// jquery file here ex. <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery..
// bootstrap.js here
</body>
```

The bootstrap banner requires the bootstrap.js for it to work, but the problem is that the links will not work. If i remove the bootstrap.js, the links will works and the banner will not. What could be a possible problem with this one?

Here's the sample.. http://jsfiddle.net/Kamirusen/AjE2M/
For this example, the banner is working but the Link at the bottom is not.. when the bootstrap.js in external file is removed the link will work, but not the banner

Comment: check for double bootstrap linking. check all included js files and make sure each one is included once.

Comment: I checked it, and all is just included once. Is it possible for me to just declare the bootstrap.js for banner only

Comment: No, you can't, it will be registered for the whole page. please create a pastebin/or anything else with your code so it can be clearer for us.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan here's the sample http://jsfiddle.net/Kamirusen/AjE2M/